# Can i change the value of interface constant (JDK9+) using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

```
public interface A
{
    int const1 = 5;
}


Class clazz=A.class;
```

How can I change const1 using reflection?
clazz.getField(????)

Comment: `int const1 5;` ? Does this compile ?

Comment: Even if you could, _you shouldn't_.

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo I was under the impression that interfaces could not have class level variables.

Comment: @Mick i just wanted to make sure, it can be a static final field, but this way, I thought it was a jdk9 new feature

Comment: @luckydog32 A member variable in an interface is implicitly `static final`

Answer (score 1):

> Can I change the value of interface constant (JDK9+) using reflection?

In general, you can't.  Certainly not in your example.

The reflective trick provided in @CardinalSystem's answer **will not work** for any constant that is initialized with a compile-time constant expression.

[17.5.3. Subsequent Modification of final Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3):

> *"Even then, there are a number of complications. If a `final` field is initialized to a constant expression (§15.28) in the field declaration, changes to the `final` field may not be observed, since uses of that `final`
>   field are replaced at compile time with the value of the constant expression."*

Notes:

1. For current generation Java tool chains / JVMs, "may not be observed" is actually "will not be observed" ... unless you are using reflection to observe the field value.
2. This does not apply to all interface fields.  While interface constants are implicitly `static` and `final`, they may be initialized with an expression that is not a constant expression.  In that case, the reflection trick should work ... provided that you take care to deal with "memory model issues".

---

Jim Garrison and others make the valid point that you *shouldn't* do this kind of thing anyway.  It leads to maintenance nightmares<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - ... of the Elm Street variety.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making the field accessible: `Field#setAccessible()` then use 
 use `getDeclaredField("modifiers")` to get the access modifiers, and then you can use `Field#setInt()` to change the modifiers so you can modify the field:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    A a = new A() {};       

    try {
        setFinalStatic(a, "const1", 2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static void setFinalStatic(Object parent, String fieldName, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    Field field = parent.getClass().getField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    System.out.print("Before : " + field.get(parent));
    field.set(parent, newValue);
    System.out.println("\tAfter : " + field.get(parent));
}
```

Comment: But you should NOT do this, or risk the murderous wrath of the programmer who must maintain your code when it breaks in production at 3:00 AM because some other programmer foolishly relied on a constant being, well, ***constant***.

Comment: @JimGarrison That's exactly why I will never implement a method like this. But the OP asked for a way to "change const1 using reflection", and that's what I gave him. If his program breaks, it will teach him to only assign final modifiers to variables that are meant to be final.

Comment: *"If his program breaks, it will teach him ..."* - Here's the problem.  Chances are that it won't teach **him**.  Chances are that it will hurt some other poor guy.  Think of the other guy!  Or to put it another way, would you give your eight year old a loaded pistol to play with?  There are better ways to learn than "the hard way".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway your discussion if it is right or not to do it... your discussion starts considering a assertion always true, but it is not so:the class when is loaded is immutable.There are context where classes are dynamic.Remember there is never a absolute right way and a absolute wrong way : it dependes by context in which your solution is running. :) :). Consider the case you want give a additional feature to a class. Java havent multiple hierarchy ... you have just interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to change final fields at runtime. 
Even if you change their value via reflection all classes that use this final field will remains with original constant value.

Answer (score -1):

Only you must change 
A a = new A() {};

on:

Class c = A.class;

You have interface:)